# how to send direct command to ev3 brick

Tags: ev3, nxt, ev3dev, python

I am new to ev3 python but am working on a project. I was reading about NXT-python that " It works by sending the direct commands detailed in LEGO's "Blue-tooth Development Kit" to the NXT brick" I was wondering is it possible to do the same with ev3 brick. Please answer in layman's terms. I am using ev3-dev and I was hoping I could use it to drive the robot.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly sending direct commands to your robot, but LEGO Education recently released [a python stack for the EV3 brick](https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/mindstorms-ev3/python-for-ev3).

I haven't tried it; but as I understand it, it's an alternative firmware which should allow you to have python scripts running natively on your EV3 brick, allowing for full autonomous robots programmed in python.